# Mobile version of site not displaying correctly on my phone

Tags: support

Most times,  I find it difficult to browse through the SO website.  The mobile version seems not compatible and does not display correctly. Also difficult to find the `ask` button until I enter the link directly in address bar

I always have to switch to full site mode. Wish this issue can be solved

[image]

Comment: What's your phone's model & OS, and what browser are you using? (If it's the official app, what version?)

Comment: Gretel GOO5
Android 4.4.2 
Opera browser

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need - did you check this? Did you try the app?

Comment: I checked the link now and my browser not supported so i downloaded the app and it's fine. Thanks Mat